# rxjs 6 - Observable<Array(Objects)> to Observable<Objects>

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have an observable that emits an array of objects. What pipe able operators do I need to use to transform it to an Observable so I can act on each object?

What do I need to do to obs$ to make it emit like obs2$ ?

```
const obs$ = of([{ opponent: 'Walton', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Scott', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Dixie', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Highlands', team: 'freshmen', gametime: new Date() }])
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  );

obs$.subscribe(a =>
  console.log(a)
);

const obs2$ = of({ opponent: 'Walton', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
  { opponent: 'Scott', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
  { opponent: 'Dixie', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
  { opponent: 'Highlands', team: 'freshmen', gametime: new Date() })
  .pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  );

obs2$.subscribe(a =>
  console.log(a)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `mergeAll`:

```js
of([2, 3, 4]).pipe(
  mergeAll()
).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
// outputs 2, 3, 4
```

If you use `from` it will work too:

```js
from([2, 3, 4])
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
// outputs 2, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `from` observable :

```
import {Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
// Write TypeScript code!

const myDatas = [{ opponent: 'Walton', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Scott', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Dixie', team: 'varsity', gametime: new Date() },
{ opponent: 'Highlands', team: 'freshmen', gametime: new Date() }];

from(myDatas).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

[live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-kikbam)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your question! I don't is it still actual, but I want to answer. I think that the source Observable cannot be changed. So, we want to *convert array to an Observable of items*. As was already mentioned, `from()` operator could help here, because it takes an array of values and emits them as values of the observable.

So, a one-time way to solve this problem is to create a pipe `pipe(switchMap(from))` it will help us. But, I would like to create a ***re-usable solution for future developers***. Something like `toStream()` operator with the same code inside. You can change the name of course!

Here a few links about my solutions:

- [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nkqftc)
- [`from()` operator documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from)

P.S. Please *left some feedback* about the answer in this way we can improve the community and motivate others to help us. Have a good day. I hope this answer was useful.